# IDE crashes despite pygame event handling. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pygame

The IDE I'm currently using is **jupyter notebook** but whenever I click on the cross button at the top of my graphic window, it stops responding. This is confusing, especially because I am breaking out the loop with event.type == pygame.QUIT in the check_events method of my class. What am I doing wrong? The following is my code:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init() #Provides access to all the features of pygame
        self.running, self.playing = True, False
        self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False
        self.DISPLAY_W, self.DISPLAY_H = 480, 270 #Display width and display height variables to determine canvas size
        #In other words, these are canvas dimensions
        self.display = pygame.Surface((self.DISPLAY_W, self.DISPLAY_H)) #Creating our canvas
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.DISPLAY_W, self.DISPLAY_H)) #Creating our window
        self.font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
        self.BLACK, self.WHITE = (0,0,0), (255,255,255) #RGB values for these colors
        
    def game_loop(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.check_events() #To see what the player is doing while playing the game
            if self.START_KEY:
                self.playing = False
            self.display.fill(self.BLACK) #Resetting our frame
            self.draw_text("Welcome to Ants vs Bees", 20, self.DISPLAY_W/2, self.DISPLAY_H/2)
            self.window.blit(self.display, (0,0)) #Aligning our display with our window
            pygame.display.update() #Moves the image onto our screen
            self.reset_keys()
            
    def check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            #Goes through a list of everything a player can do on the computer
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #To check if players hits the cross button at top of window
                self.running, self.playing = False, False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: #To check if enter key was pressed
                        self.START_KEY = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE: #To check if backspace key was pressed
                        self.BACK_KEY = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #To check if down key was pressed
                        self.DOWN_KEY = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #To check if up key was pressed
                        self.UP_KEY = True
                    
    def reset_keys(self):
        self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False
        
    def draw_text(self, text, size, x, y):
        font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_name, size) #Loading up our font
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, self.WHITE) #Creates a rectangular image of our text
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (x,y)
        self.display.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

#Driver code
firstrun = Game()

while firstrun.running:
    firstrun.playing = True
    firstrun.game_loop()
```

Comment: You need to call `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()`

Comment: Why do you have 2 main loops with the same exit condition? Either one or the other will have no effect

Comment: @mousetail because the two loops will allow me to switch between menus, which I am currently in the process of implementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `check_events` function:

```
    def check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            #Goes through a list of everything a player can do on the computer
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #To check if players hits the cross button at top of window
                self.running, self.playing = False, False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: #To check if enter key was pressed
                        self.START_KEY = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE: #To check if backspace key was pressed
                        self.BACK_KEY = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #To check if down key was pressed
                        self.DOWN_KEY = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #To check if up key was pressed
                        self.UP_KEY = True
```

You've indented the `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` into the `if event.type == pygame.QUIT` statement. Try:

```
    def check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            #Goes through a list of everything a player can do on the computer
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #To check if players hits the cross button at top of window
                self.running, self.playing = False, False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: #To check if enter key was pressed
                    self.START_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE: #To check if backspace key was pressed
                    self.BACK_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #To check if down key was pressed
                    self.DOWN_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #To check if up key was pressed
                    self.UP_KEY = True
```

Finally, add a `pygame.quit()` at the end of your `game_loop` function:

```
    def game_loop(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.check_events() #To see what the player is doing while playing the game
            if self.START_KEY:
                self.playing = False
            self.display.fill(self.BLACK) #Resetting our frame
            self.draw_text("Welcome to Ants vs Bees", 20, self.DISPLAY_W/2, self.DISPLAY_H/2)
            self.window.blit(self.display, (0,0)) #Aligning our display with our window
            pygame.display.update() #Moves the image onto our screen
            self.reset_keys()
        pygame.quit()
```